# Multiple where condition in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

MyTable

```
ID | Name | Type 
---+------+-----
1  | asd  | A
2  | zxc  | B
3  | qwe  | A
```

First query

```
select ID, TypeA_Name from MyTable Where Type = 'A'
```

Gives

```
ID | TypeA_Name
---+-----------
1  | asd
3  | qwe
```

Second Query

```
select ID, TypeB_Name MyTable Where Type = 'B'
```

Gives

```
ID | TypeB_Name
---+-----------
2  | zxc
```

I wand TypeA_Name and TypeB_Name in single query a below

```
select ID, TypeA_Name, TypeB_Name from MyTable
```

Should Give

```
ID | TypeA_Name | TypeB_Name
---+------------+-----------
1  | asd        | ---
2  | ---        | zxc
3  | qwe        | ---
```

Then how can I frame where clause ?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    ID,
    case when Type='A' then Name else null end as TypeA_Name,
    case when Type='B' then Name else null end as TypeB_Name
from MyTable
```

you can use your `WHERE`s normally eg `Where Type = 'A'`